# Iphone sdk sample AVCam to drive the following error has occurred

Tags: iphone, avcam

**Iphone sdk sample AVCam to drive the following error has occurred.**

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/Frameworks/CydiaSubstrate.framework/Libraries/SubstrateLoader.dylib (file not found).
2011-05-17 14:12:15.927 AVCam[225:607] MS:Notice: Installing: com.224ok.movieplayer [AVCam] (550.58)
2011-05-17 14:12:15.973 AVCam[225:607] MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/3GMy3G.dylib
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/3GMy3G.dylib (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.2 (8H7)/Symbols/usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.2 (8H7)/Symbols/usr/lib/libsubstrate.dylib (file not found).
2011-05-17 14:12:16.393 AVCam[225:607] My3G waiting for User Prompt in com.224ok.movieplayer  v4.8..
2011-05-17 14:12:16.408 AVCam[225:607] MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib (file not found).
2011-05-17 14:12:16.823 AVCam[225:607] MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/AskToCall.dylib
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/AskToCall.dylib (file not found).
MS:Warning: nil class argument
MS:Warning: nil class argument
2011-05-17 14:12:17.084 AVCam[225:607] MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Backgrounder.dylib
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Backgrounder.dylib (file not found).
2011-05-17 14:12:17.300 AVCam[225:607] MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/KeyboardFix.dylib
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/KeyboardFix.dylib (file not found).
2011-05-17 14:12:17.486 AVCam[225:607] MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Springtomize.dylib
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Springtomize.dylib (file not found).
MS:Warning: nil class argument
/* last message repeated many times */
MS:Warning: nil class argument
2011-05-17 14:12:17.711 AVCam[225:607] [Springtomize]: factor: 0.500000
2011-05-17 14:12:17.716 AVCam[225:607] MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/SwipeToMoveCursor.dylib
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/SwipeToMoveCursor.dylib (file not found).
MS:Warning: nil class argument
2011-05-17 14:12:17.872 AVCam[225:607] MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/WinterBoard.dylib
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/WinterBoard.dylib (file not found).
2011-05-17 14:12:18.064 AVCam[225:607] WB:Notice: WinterBoard
MS:Warning: message not found [UIImage defaultDesktopImage]
2011-05-17 14:12:18.104 AVCam[225:607] MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/biteSBarClient.dylib
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/biteSBarClient.dylib (file not found).
2011-05-17 14:12:18.328 AVCam[225:607] MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/libstatusbar.dylib
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/libstatusbar.dylib (file not found).
2011-05-17 14:12:18.532 AVCam[225:607] MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/sandcastleclient.dylib
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/sandcastleclient.dylib (file not found).
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.2 (8H7)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).
(gdb) continue
Program received signal:  “SIGUSR1”.
warning: Remote failure reply: E37
(gdb) continue
```

**I mean why run without modification?**

Comment: 1. Good formatting is your friend, 2. Paste some code not only your error message..

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is *probably* that you're trying to use XCode with a jailbroken iPhone, and XCode is trying (unsuccessfully) to find symbols that aren't there for libraries like `CydiaSubstrate`. If so, you may have to reinstall iOS and forego jailbreaking to get XCode and your phone to play nice together.